Post a chart to Slack via Python - without 3rd party
Is there a way to post to Slack via python (either using requests via the slack API, or another python library), without having to use third party hosting?
There's a previous stackoverflow question that suggests it's possible (Post a pyplot image to Slack), but the Slacker library appears to be broken now, and unsupported.
Basically it sounds like I need to upload a file and unfurl it using requests.post. I'm looking for an example of how I can include a file in there (saved from a pyplot for eg), then have the slack bot display it in the chat. Any ideas?
Thx
